# Toshiba A665 laptop asks me for a password after starting

Tags: passwords

I have a Toshiba A665 laptop. All of a sudden now when it starts, a black screen pops up asking for password.  I know the password but I don't know why this has started happening. How do I get this to not come up?

Comment: Tapping Esc key at the bios starup should bring up a menu of sorts, which will indicate which key to press to enter the bios

Answer (score 1):

Get into the Setup (key to access SETUP should show up on boot screen, usually Del, F2 or something similar) and disable boot password.

Comment: I've gone into that but it won't let me disable. ???

Comment: Please be more specific: how it does not let you disable? Any message?

Comment: I go into setup and it doesn't give me an option to disable boot password.  Please help!

Comment: You should really search better and you will find it